# redundant id values inserted despite using @inheritance

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

In a spring mvc app using hibernate, jpa, and MySQL, I have a `BaseEntity` that contains an `id` field that is unique across all classes that inherit from `BaseEntity`, using `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)`.  Some data is imported into the MySQL database using an external `dml.sql` file run from the command line.  The imported data is carefully planned so that all the `id`s that need to be managed as part of the `BaseEntity` inheritance group are unique within their inheritance group.

The problem is that hibernate is not taking the values of the `id`s already in the database into account when it inserts a new record into the database.  Instead, hibernate is saving an `id` value in one of the descendent entities which is identical to an `id` stored in one of the other descendent entities.

**How can I configure hibernate to respect the `id` values already in the database when it saves a new entity within the same inheritance group?**

**Some relevant facts are**:

All of the objects in the MySQL database were created directly from the hibernate mappings in the app by using `hbm2ddl`.

I cannot use `@MappedSuperClass` for `BaseEntity` because `BaseEntity` is used as a property of one of the entities in the app, so that entities of various types can be stored in the same property of that entity.  When I was using `@MappedSuperClass`, eclipse was giving compile errors saying that `BaseEntity` cannot be instantiated directly because it has `@MappedSuperClass` annotation.

**Note:** The file sharing site seems to be center-justifying all the code.  You can fix this by simply cutting and pasting it into a text editor.

You can read the code for BaseEntity [by clicking on this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/ml7ziWN7gdrRAwsro9yD?b=mKTlldJRrL0qhKEG88nT).

The code for the entity whose id values are being set incorrectly by hibernate can be read by clicking [on this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/YTW2BDYHF5TWgs8W6NoN).

The jpql code for saving the entity whose id is being set incorrectly is as follows:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void saveCCD(HL7ConsolidatedCareDocument ccd) {
    if (ccd.getId() == null) {
        this.em.persist(ccd);
        this.em.flush();
    }
    else {
        this.em.merge(ccd);
        this.em.flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to find out what hibernate's ID generation strategy is for your inheritance strategy on mysql (probably TABLE) and make sure the way you allocate id's in your SQL is compatible with that strategy.

Comment: @Eelke Please see the code for `BaseEntity` in the link above.  Here is the relevant segment: `@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    protected Integer id;`  All the SQL DDL is created by `hbm2ddl`.  Do you need to see the SQL `INSERT` statements that are being generated by hibernate?  What could I provide that could help you see a specific solution in code form?

Answer (score 1):

I have never done this using hibernate or mysql ut have done something similar with EclipseLink + PostgreSQL. So there might be some mistakes below.

With generation type TABLE you might want to explicitly specify some additional parameters using the TableGenerator annotation. That way you are certain where hibernate is storing things.

```
@Id 
@GeneratedValue(
    strategy=GenerationType.TABLE, 
    generator="TBL_GEN")
@javax.persistence.TableGenerator(
    name="TBL_GEN",
    table="GENERATOR_TABLE",
    pkColumnName = "mykey",
    valueColumnName = "hi"
    pkColumnValue="BaseEntity_Id",
    allocationSize=20
)
```

What you need to do when you bypass hibernate is to reserve the ids you need by updating the row with mykey BaseEntity_Id in the table GENERATOR_TABLE.

For details on the annotations see [paragraph 5.1.2.2](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id)

Comment: Should have known better key is indeed a standard SQL keyword. Updated the answer.

Comment: As I examine this more closely, I see that `generator_table` still does not take into account pre-existing values of keys that were imported into the database from external scripts.  This will not solve my problem unless hibernate can check pre-existing values of the keys before setting/using the value in `hi`.